In Javascript, how can I pass a value into a function that is a parameter of another function?
I have a function that works on an array of objects. But sometimes it uses one value from the object and sometimes another, and sometimes it uses a value from the object to look something up in a different object. So no problem, with Javascript I can pass a function as a parameter, and write a function that retries the relevant value.
So forget the array business, let me give a simplified version of the function here that eliminates all the complexity not relevant to my question. Say we just want to compare "some" value from two objects. So I wrote this:
function compareThem(a,b,f) {
  return f(a)==f(b)
}

So if the objects contain a member called "value1", I could write:
let flag=compareThem(a,b,(o1) => o1.value1)

Or if I want to compare value2, I could write:
let flag=compareThem(a,b,(o1) => o1.value2)

Cool. But here's the catch. Sometimes I need data that isn't in the object. Like in one case the object includes an array and I want to examine a particular element in that array. If I knew it was always, say, #7, I could write
let flag=compareThem(a,b,(o1) => o1.myarray[7])

But the problem is, the index is in a variable. What I really want to say is
let flag=compareThem(a,b,(o1) => o1.myarray[x])

But how do I get the value of x in there? In my first draft I added a parameter for x, but that was a problem because every time I call the function I use different data, and I didn't want to have a whole bunch of parameters each one only applicable to one call.
I eventually figured out that the scope of the call is within the scope of the caller, so I could say
let x=1
let flag=compareThem(a,b,(o1) => o1.myarray[x])

and that works. But that seems really ugly -- passing data to a function magically like that. I really want to put it in the function definition somehow. But how do I tell JS that this is a value passed in from the caller, and not a local variable within the function? Is there any way to say that?

But how do I tell JS that this is a value passed in from the caller, and not a local variable within the function? Is there any way to say that? Yeah. Its called a parameter.

@tkausl But as I explained in the post, I don't want to pass it in as a parameter to the "outer" function, compareThem, because I need different data with every invocation. I want to pass it to the inner function.

You could pass a partially applied function using bind():


function compareThem(a, b, f) {
  return f(a) == f(b);
}

const a = { myarray: [10, 20] };
const b = { myarray: [100, 20] };

let flag = compareThem(a, b, ((index, o) => o.myarray[index]).bind(null, 1));

console.log(flag)




Another option is to add the extra data as properties on the callback function:
const fn = (o) => o.myarray[fn.index];
fn.index = 1;

let flag = compareThem(a, b, fn);


Another option is to use a higher-order function:
const fn = (index) => (o) => o.myarray[index];
let flag = compareThem(a, b, fn(1));


bind is a bit strange, but a closure (last one) is great.

The second option is basically the same as thelet x=1 solution OP has presented and deemed "too magical".

@kaiido In fairness, at least it ties the extra data to the function, so when it's used in the callback, there's no sense of "hey, where did this come from?" But I like #3 better as cleaner.

@Jay yes index is less "magical", but then you have "hey where did fn comes from?". So it's really just the same as yours, arguably even less clear since attaching properties to functions isn't something that common.
